# Using SQL like with range operator in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, sql-like, databricks-sql

In a Databricks SQL endpoint, the SQL like with range operator is not working.

Ex1:-

with Cte_Members AS

( Select '1A' as Memid

union all

Select '2B' as Memid

union all

Select '3C' as Memid

union all

Select 'DD' as Memid

)

select * from Cte_Members where Memid like '[0-9]%'

Result:- 0 records

Ex2:-
with Cte_Members AS

( Select '1A' as Memid

union all

Select '2B' as Memid

union all

Select '3C' as Memid

union all

Select 'DD' as Memid

)

select * from Cte_Members where Memid like '2%'

Result:- We are getting one record with "2B" as Memid

Comment: hi @Rajashekhar, can you provide `Cte_Members` schema of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **`rlike`** instead of like for regex match **`^[0-9]`**.

```
with Cte_Members AS
( Select '1A' as Memid
union all
Select '2B' as Memid
union all
Select '3C' as Memid
union all
Select 'DD' as Memid
)
select * from Cte_Members where Memid rlike '^[0-9]'
#Memid
#1A
#2B
#3C
```

Comment: but, it is failing for "E234" Memid. We need to fetch Memid starting with numbers.

Comment: Try with `rlike '^[0-9]'`